# How to create tag by variable from azure pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I try to create tag in triggers -> Tag format, with my variable - BUILD_VERSION

[image]

This variable i used in pipeline for tagging build by following cmd scripts:

```yaml
  - task: CmdLine@2
    displayName: 'Get release version'
    inputs:
      script: |
        BUILD_VERSION=$(mvn -f $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/$(Build.Repository.Name)/pom.xml --pl axilink help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version -q -DforceStdout)
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=BUILD_VERSION]$BUILD_VERSION"
        echo "##vso[build.addbuildtag]$BUILD_VERSION"
        echo "##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]$(Build.BuildNumber)-$BUILD_VERSION"
        tag="##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]$(Build.BuildNumber)-$BUILD_VERSION"
        echo $BUILD_VERSION
```

When i used $BUILD_VERSION in tag source, i see $BUILD_VERSION like text, but not a variable with my value.
[image]
How can i use my variable for tag source in triggers pipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two tags in DevOps: **pipeline tag** and **git tag**.

In yaml you are using [logging command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#addbuildtag-add-a-tag-to-the-build) to add the `pipeline build tag` not git tag.

In the `tag setting` below, it's git tag, but it only accepts `predefined variable` and `user-defined` variables. **It gets the tag value during the compile time, while not during the run-time, it cannot get the value which is setting during the pipeline.**

[image]

If you would like to set the **git tag** with the variable which is setting in pipeline, you can use rest api [Annotated Tags - Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/annotated-tags/create?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP) to add the git tag.

Sample code below:

```
  - task: CmdLine@2
    displayName: 'Get release version'
    inputs:
      script: |
        BUILD_VERSION=0.0.8-test
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=BUILD_VERSION]$BUILD_VERSION"
        echo $BUILD_VERSION

  - pwsh: |
      $header = @{Authorization = "Bearer $(System.AccessToken)"}
      $url="$(System.CollectionUri)/$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/git/repositories/$(Build.Repository.ID)/annotatedtags?api-version=7.1-preview.1"
      write-host $url
      $body = '
      { 
        "name": "$(BUILD_VERSION)",
        "taggedObject": {
          "objectId": "$(Build.SourceVersion)"
        },
        "message": "Git tag add"
      }
      '
      Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers $header -Method Post -ContentType "application/json" -Body ($body)
    displayName: 'Add tag'
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Nikolay Debolsky, may i know if it helps? Or you still have any queries? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for help. I decided my task in a similar way. But i used bash without powershell