# Azure DevOps YML pipeline versioning

Tags: yaml, azure-pipelines

I want to be able to version/tag a yaml pipeline but can't find a good way of doing so.

The idea is to be able to update jobs, stages, tasks and be able to roll back any changes to the yaml at the click of a button.

The only way I can see of doing this so far is using branches. Is there a better way?

What I'm looking for is a method similar to setting a variable as a version number and using templates to invoke a different version of the yaml file. But this would mean having multiple files.

The ability to use a a tag as the default branch would be ideal - is this possible?

[image: Azure DevOps default branches]

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that there is no another way to achieve version control like branch based on the current Azure Devops docs.You can combine branch and tag to better control which repo files you want to use in your yaml pipeline.

Besides you could submit any comments and proposals for future releases and implementations via:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps/suggest?space=21

Answer (score 0):

> The ability to use a a tag as the default branch would be ideal - is this possible?

For **Classic** UI Pipeline, the default branch **only accept branches, not tags**. You can create a new branch on the build commit.You can get the commit from predefined variable `$(Build.SourceVersion)`.

Steps below:

1. Add PAT token variable, and add powershell task:
   [image]

code below:

```
$personalToken = "$(personalToken)"
$token =   [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($personalToken)"))
$header = @{authorization = "Basic $token"}
$url="$(System.CollectionUri)/$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/git/repositories/$(Build.Repository.ID)/refs?api-version=5.0-preview.1"
write-host $url
echo $(Build.SourceVersion)
$body = @"
[{"name":"refs/heads/newbranch1","newObjectId":"$(Build.SourceVersion)","oldObjectId":"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"}]
"@
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers $header -Method Post -ContentType "application/json" -Body ($body)
```

After the build, you can find the branch:
[image]

Or you can use **yaml** type pipeline, you can choose `branch` or `git tag`, or even directly specific the `commit id` to run the build. You can check my answer in this [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77270047/14996050) about how to add the git tag on the commit.

[image]

> The idea is to be able to update jobs, stages, tasks and be able to roll back any changes to the yaml at the click of a button.

If you only need the yaml file, not need other source files in the repo, you can click on the commit on pipeline result page, it will redirect to change files page, click "browser files" to go the commit source file page, you can directly copy the yaml file content.
[image]